# Validate each object in a complex JSON string

Tags: java, json

Need your expert advise here. So I have a complex JSON string that has multiple Java objects. Here is my JSON string. I have only listed one java object but it has plenty (each mapped to a java class in my code)

```
{
  "myStoreInfo": {
    "id": "12370034",
    "address": australia,
    "partnerInfo": {
      "retailPartner": false
    },
    "customerContactInfo": {
      "name": {
        "firstName": "Ricky",
        "middleName": "Sage",
        "lastName": "Higging",
        "gender": "Male",
      },
      "customerPhone": {
        "areaCode": "",
        "extension": "",
        "completeNumber": "1234567",        
      },
      "contactEmail": {
        "emailAddress": "ricky@gmail.com"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I basically need to validate a few elements in the entire JSON string to make sure they are not null. Here is the code for validation -

```
public static String validateJSON(String jsonFile, Object objToValidate) throws JSONException {  
        JSONObject myStoreInfo = jsonFileObj.getJSONObject("myStoreInfo");  
        JSONObject jsonObj = null;
            if(myStoreInfo!=null) {          
                if(myStoreInfo.isNull("id"))                
                    return "myStoreInfo info id is null";
                if(myStoreInfo.isNull("address"))
                    return "myStoreInfo address field is null"; 
            jsonObj = myStoreInfo.getJSONObject("partnerInfo");
            if(jsonObj!=null) {
                if(jsonObj.isNull("retailPartner"))
                    return "partner info retail partner is null";
            }
            jsonObj = myStoreInfo.getJSONObject("customerContactInfo");
            JSONObject name = jsonObj.getJSONObject("name");
            if(name!=null) {
                if(name.isNull("firstName"))                
                    return "myStoreInfo first name is null";
                if(name.isNull("lastName"))             
                    return "myStoreInfo last name is null";
            }
            jsonObj = myStoreInfo.getJSONObject("customerContactInfo");
            jsonObj = jsonObj.getJSONObject("contactEmail");
            if(jsonObj==null)               
                    return "myStoreInfo email id is null";
            }
           return null;       
        }
}
```

This works well if I am doing the validation for one java object, and my json file has that java object only. But the fact is my json file has too many of these strings that internally map to various java objects. My question here is - I need to be able to pass these objects to validate them individually. As you can see here, my validateJSON takes the object to pass as an argument. How do I split the JSON string for each object, and validate all the fields within that object are fine?

Comment: You could use Java Reflection to traverse through the deserialized object tree and validate all non primitive fields for beeing not null.

Comment: Anything easier? There has to be a way to split a JSON string at each corresponding java object, and traverse through its elements. This has to be a common use case. I can't seem to find a solution :( Anyone?

Comment: use jackson to create tree-models, which then can be traversed more easily and searched form nulls. cf http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonTreeModel

Answer (score 0):

As you have too many arrays in that json string converting to Java Array list might be easier

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonFile);
for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
JSONObject json = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(jsonArray[i]);
//convert to java list
}
```